# Merge based on "group by" groups

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

So I have a table called the `Activities` table that contains a schema of `user_id, activity`

There is a row for each user, activity combo.
Here is a what it might look like (empty rows added to make things easier to look at, please ignore):

```
| user_id | activity  |
|---------|-----------|
| 1       | swimming  | -- We want to match this
| 1       | running   | -- person's activities
|         |           |
| 2       | swimming  |
| 2       | running   |
| 2       | rowing    |
|         |           |
| 3       | swimming  |
|         |           |
| 4       | skydiving |
| 4       | running   |
| 4       | swimming  |
```

I would like to basically find all other users with *at least* the same activities as a given input `id` so that I could recommend users with similar activities.

so in the table above, if I wanna find recommended users for `user_id=1`, the query would return `user_id=2` and `user_id=4` because they engage in both `swimming, running` (and more), but not `user_id=3` because they only engage in `swimming`

So a result with a single column of:

```
| user_id |
|---------|
| 2       |
| 4       |
```

is what I would ideally be looking for

---

As far as what I've tried, I am kinda stuck at how to get a solid set of `user_id=1`'s activities to match against. Basically I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
SELECT user_id from Activities
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING input_user_activities in user_x_activities
```

where user1_activities is just a set of our input user's activities. I can create that set using a `WITH input_user_activities AS (...)` in the beginning, what I'm stuck at is the `user_x_activities` part

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sample table data is great, but also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get users with the same activities, you can use a self join.  Let me assume that the rows are unique:

```
select a.user_id
from activities a1 join
     activities a
     on a1.activity = a.activity and
        a1.user_id = @user_id
group by a.user_id
having count(*) = (select count(*) from activities a1 where a1.user_id = @user_id);
```

The `having` clause answers your question -- of getting users that have the same activities as a given user.

Comment: I like this. It's what I was I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: @QuantumHoneybees how does this answer your question? If there are not any users exactly the same number of activities as the user you search for don't you want the others with 1 activity less?

Comment: Fair question, but in this scenario, those users don't meet the minimum qualification of what I call "a matching recommendation". @JoachimIsaksson's answer is more generalizable, but this is purely based on personal preference

Comment: I see now that you have edited and changed the original requirement. This is not the way you should ask questions.

Comment: @forpas . . . I'm not sure what you are referring to.  The original question explicitly stated:  "I would like to basically find all other users with at least the same activities as a given input id so that I could recommend users with similar activities."  This answers that question; the later edits are clarifications.

Comment: @GordonLinoff check the sample data of the original post: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58158534/1 and *so in the table above, if I wanna find recommended users for user_id=1, the query would user_id=2 because they engage in both swimming, running, but not user_id=3 because they only engage in swimming*

Comment: @GordonLinoff for that original post your query would not return results because there is no user with all 3 activities of user = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get all users ordered by similarity using a `JOIN` (that finds all common rows) and a `GROUP BY` (to summarize the similarity per user_id) and finally an `ORDER BY` to return the most similar users first.

```
SELECT b.user_id, COUNT(*) similarity
FROM activities a
JOIN activities b
  ON a.activity = b.activity
WHERE a.user_id = 1 AND b.user_id != 1
GROUP BY b.user_id
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3e0c63/1).

Comment: I like this idea, is there no way to access a group by's group directly? Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you only want the most similar users (as in your example above) without knowing how similar they are?

Comment: So your query is perfect. It works for me and it works very fast. But yes, in order to learn, I want to see if there's a better approach if we only want the similar users without knowing how similar they are (as long as they have the same activities of the input user)